# Modify script to copy data validation from a list and timestamp on edit of that data validation to new rows each time an edit is made

Tags: google-sheets

I created a sign out for study halls where students select from a dropdown on the master page to find their destination which also creates a timestamp and copies the row to another tab which each homeroom teacher can monitor to see who should be in their room and when they left the previous room. This way teachers can look at their individual pages to see who should be in their rooms at any time, they will know who is supposed to be coming to their rooms, and they have access to where their kids are going to on the master sheet if needed.

Some teachers have asked about using this system throughout the day as they have wandering students or students that try to leave every period. Right now, the script I am running will update the drop-down column and timestamp on each edit, but I would also like to copy the edited dropdown and timestamp information to new columns on the master each time a student checks out of one room to go to another. This way teachers could see on the master list where and when students are going across classes which could help identify issues that might need to be addressed. I created new columns called Destination 1 and Time 1, Destination 2, and Time 2, etc. but I am not sure how to get the information to those columns. Each time a student leaves, I would want the information to be put into the first available column next to their name.

FYI, I have only modified a few scripts previously, and do not write my own scripts.

Link to a copy of the Google Doc I setup. The Master tab has a copy of all the students and each of the other tabs pulls information from the master based on what is selected in row F.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JDdiKGGIaOVBUSIVxOTK56uceerR1iNuoD7wKowqAfU/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "EST";
  var timestamp_format = "HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "Student Destination";
  var timeStampColName = "Time";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Master'); //Name of the 
sheet where you want to run this script.

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = 
updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // 
only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the 
header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, 
timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

When I choose a destination in row F, the timestamp is generated and the others tabs are updated. I just need to copy each of the edit results to new columns which I have named Destination 1 and Time 1, Destination 2, and Time 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The OP code is good but doesn't make use of onEdit. The `event` parameter of the onEdit function/trigger provides data concerning the edit. Details are described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

In the scenario that the OP has outlined, the first issue is to evaluate whether there is already a time in Column G.

**EXISTING TIME?**
If there is an existing time, then any existing data in Destination 1 to 5 must be copied to destinations 2 to 6, then the existing student name and time must be copied to Destination 1, and then, and only then, can the new date can be applied.

**1- Existing data in Destination 1 to 5 must be copied to destinations 2 to 6**

```
var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(actRngRow, 9, 1, 10);
rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(actRngRow, 11));
```

This leaves room to copy/paste the existing student name and time to destination 1.

**2- Copy the existing student name and time to Destination 1**

```
var oldDate = sheet.getRange(actRngRow, actRngCol + 1);`
This is simply the column beside the edited cell.

// copy the old student name and date to destination 1
var oldStudentName = event.oldValue;
var oldDateValue = oldDate.getValue();
var Dest1StudentName = actRng.offset(0, 3).setValue(oldStudentName);
var Dest1DateValue = actRng.offset(0, 4).setValue(oldDateValue);
```

`offset` enables the code to use a relative reference. In this case, the column reference is the number of columns to the right of the edited cell. The name of the student is made available by `event.oldValue`, and the time is the value in Column G (because we haven't yet updated that column).

**INSERT UPDATED TIME IN COLUMN G**
The existing code works well

```
// add the date to the adjacent cell
var cell = sheet.getRange(actRngRow, actRngCol + 1);
var newdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
cell.setValue(newdate);
```

The complete code is:

```
function onEdit(event) {
    Logger.log("start onedit");
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master")
    //so_53888444
    var timezone = "EST";
    var timestamp_format = "HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
    var updateColName = "Student Destination";
    var timeStampColName = "Time";
    //var debug_e = {
    //  authMode:  event.authMode,  
    //  range:  event.range.getA1Notation(),    
    //  source:  event.source.getId(),
    //  user:  event.user,   
    //  value:  event.value,
    //  oldValue: event. oldValue
    //};
    //Logger.log("AuthMode: "+debug_event.authMode);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("Range: "+debug_event.range);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("Source: "+debug_event.source);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("User: "+debug_event.user);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("user email"+debug_event.user.getEmail());// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("Value: "+debug_event.value);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("Old value: "+debug_event.oldValue);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("AuthMode: "+debug_event.authMode+", Range: "+debug_event.range+", source: "+debug_event.source+", user: "+debug_event.user+", value: "+debug_event.value+", old value: "+debug_event.oldValue);// DEBUG
    //Logger.log("the old value: "+event.oldValue);
    var actRng = event.range;
    //Logger.log("the edited range was " + actRng.getA1Notation()); //DEBUG
    var actRngRow = actRng.getRow();
    var actRngCol = actRng.getColumn();
    var oldDate = sheet.getRange(actRngRow, actRngCol + 1);
    var status = 0;
    if (actRngRow > 1 && actRngCol == 6) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row 
        if (oldDate.isBlank()) {
            //Logger.log("the date is blank - no historic data to copy");
        } else {
            //Logger.log("the date NOT  blank - copy the historic data");
            // copy/paste existing destinations
            var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(actRngRow, 9, 1, 10);
            rangeToCopy.copyTo(sheet.getRange(actRngRow, 11));

            // copy the old student name and date to destination 1
            var oldStudentName = event.oldValue;
            var oldDateValue = oldDate.getValue();
            var Dest1StudentName = actRng.offset(0, 3).setValue(oldStudentName);
            var Dest1DateValue = actRng.offset(0, 4).setValue(oldDateValue);
        }

        // add the date to the adjacent cell
        var cell = sheet.getRange(actRngRow, actRngCol + 1);
        var newdate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
        cell.setValue(newdate);
    }

}
```